# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I was just trying to teach myself how to work with databases in SQL Server, watching my first tutorial. The guy got it all right, but I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near 'rollno'.

The code:

```
create database mytestdb

create table mytesttable
(
    rollno int,
    firstname varchar(50),
    lastname varchar(50)
)
```

Being a beginner, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Try `create database mytestdb GO  USE mytestdb GO create table mytesttable ( rollno int, firstname varchar(50), lastname varchar(50) )`

Comment: Where do you run this script? If run your code in SSMS then everything Ok

Comment: SQL statements need to be terminated with a `;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
create database mytestdb;
GO

USE mytestdb;
GO

create table mytesttable
(
rollno int,
firstname varchar(50),
lastname varchar(50)
);
GO
```

When you execute all the statements in one go, without the key word (batch sperator `GO`) sql server tried to execute all the statements as one piece of work. But there are certainly rules in sql server which tell you what statements can or can't be executed as one piece of work(in one batch).

Hence use the key word `GO` to tell sql server you want these pieces of work executed separately, mind you `GO` is not T-SQL it is SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) term.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but if you already terminate each statement properly with a `;` then the GO isn't needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed, it happens due to Unicode File's Byte Order Mark (BOM). It can preset as a non-visible character, and invalidates the SQL syntax.

If I copy/paste the SQL, it works. If I load the file, it won't.

[Here is how to fix.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295463.aspx) (an example only).

You can remove those marks by opening the file in notepad and saving as an ANSI Encoding while saving the file.

[image]
See the first few characters in a plain text file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create database mytestdb;
GO

USE mytestdb

create table mytesttable
(
rollno int,
firstname varchar(50),
lastname varchar(50)
);
```

Comment: @fraserjordan Before your edit, in previous version you just added ';'. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx) "Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions (Transact-SQL)" ; == Transact-SQL statement terminator. Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version